# Rank grades as object values from highest to lowest

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, rank

I want to get the first name and the gwa from each object, then arrange them according to their gwa from highest to lowest. I got the "getting the first name and gwa" part but I don't know how to arrange them according to their gwa.

I tried to use sort() but I seems to have used it in a wrong way. Can anyone please help me?

```
const students = [
{
    firstName: "Jose",
    lastName: "Valenci",
    gender: "male",
    gwa: 98, 
    interest: "tennis"
},

{
    firstName: "Debby",
    lastName: "Smith",
    gender: "female",
    gwa: 96,
    interest: "singing"
},

{
    firstName: "Zaira",
    lastName: "Pay",
    gender: "female",
    gwa: 93,
    interest: "crafts"
}];


const basedOnGwa = students.map ((name,grade) => {
let{lastName} = name;
let {gwa} = grade;
grade = grade.sort(grade1 => {
    let {gwa} = grade1;
    return grade1;
}); 

return grade();
})

console.log(basedOnGwa);
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a new object with only the `lastName`s and `gwa`s, or are you trying to sort the input array?

Comment: Your problem starts with the `map` function. Please read the docs and try again. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Using map wrong. Read docs for what arguments are. Also using sort wrong. There is no way this code is not throwing errors. Always start in browser console and resolving errors thrown

Comment: If I do this 
    const basedOnGwa = students.map (name => {
 let{lastName, gwa} = name;
  
 return `${lastName} : ${gwa}`;;
    })

    console.log(basedOnGwa);

I got what I want to get, but I don't know how to arrange them from highest  to lowest according to their grades.

Comment: Suggestion: Don't try to do everything all at once. Get your new array working. Then worry about sorting

Comment: Use sort on `basedOnGwa ` array . Can chain it after map() or run it separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```js
const students = [
{
    firstName: "Jose",
    lastName: "Valenci",
    gender: "male",
    gwa: 98, 
    interest: "tennis"
},

{
    firstName: "Debby",
    lastName: "Smith",
    gender: "female",
    gwa: 96,
    interest: "singing"
},

{
    firstName: "Zaira",
    lastName: "Pay",
    gender: "female",
    gwa: 93,
    interest: "crafts"
}];


var basedOnGwa = students.reduce((arr,v,i)=>{
   return arr.concat({'firstName':v.firstName,'gwa':v.gwa});
},[]);
basedOnGwa.sort((a,b)=>{
   return b.gwa - a.gwa;
})
console.log(basedOnGwa);
```

EDIT

If you want to use `map` instead of `reduce` you can follow the following code:

```js
const students = [
{
    firstName: "Jose",
    lastName: "Valenci",
    gender: "male",
    gwa: 98, 
    interest: "tennis"
},

{
    firstName: "Debby",
    lastName: "Smith",
    gender: "female",
    gwa: 96,
    interest: "singing"
},

{
    firstName: "Zaira",
    lastName: "Pay",
    gender: "female",
    gwa: 93,
    interest: "crafts"
}];


var basedOnGwa = students.map((v,i)=>{
   return {'firstName':v.firstName,'gwa':v.gwa};
});
basedOnGwa.sort((a,b)=>{
   return b.gwa - a.gwa;
})
console.log(basedOnGwa);
```

Comment: Suggest using map() instead of reduce just to show OP how to use it properly. Is simpler than reduce for this anyway